# change bootstrap icon by change value whi in js

Tags: javascript, icons, addeventlistener, onchange, audio-player

I have took 3 icons from bootstarp in this 3 icons I have use 1 icon which name is bi-volum-up-fill other two icons use in js fill or in this logic.But in this case I am not able to change my icons by id name deepended on change event value. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPht9.png)

Comment: Kindly opt for sharing code in textual form rather than using images. When using an event, you can use its `target` property to refer to the element that triggered it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.